# lvremove is not removing previous LV'S filesystem signature. Is it safe to remove it while using lvcreate?

Tags: partition, lvm

I removed a logical volume that was formatted with `ext4` with no data in it. I then proceeded to create a `swap` LVM but it's giving me a warning that there is an `ext4` signature present. I am assuming that `lvremove` command doesn't remove the fs signature. Is it safe to remove the signature when prompted using `lvcreate`?

```
[root@workstation ~]# lvs
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home cl   -wi-ao----  <6.52g                                                    
  root cl   -wi-ao----  19.00g                                                    
  swap cl   -wi-ao----   2.00g                                                    
  lv01 vg01 -wi-a----- 404.00m                                                    
  lv02 vg01 -wi-a----- 100.00m                                                    
[root@workstation ~]# lvremove /dev/vg01/lv02
Do you really want to remove active logical volume vg01/lv02? [y/n]: y
  Logical volume "lv02" successfully removed.
[root@workstation ~]# 
[root@workstation ~]# 
[root@workstation ~]# lvcreate -n swap1 -L 100M vg01
WARNING: ext4 signature detected on /dev/vg01/swap1 at offset 1080. Wipe it? [y/n]:
```

Comment: Rather than create `swap1` why not resize the existing `swap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `lvremove` doesn't remove the filesystem signature from the LV and yes, it is safe to remove it during `lvcreate`. `lvcreate` will just write zeroes to the first few sectors of the newly create LV.

It's generally a good idea to remove the filesystem signature with `wipefs` before removing partitions and other block devices to avoid this.